# Two identical strings, yet different lengths. Trimmed, cleansed, etc

Tags: php

I have two strings, one is generated by PHP and stored in a database at 128 characters. The generated string is e-mailed to the user and they must input the string.

Now for some reason, the one from the user (with me testing), is 132 characters long through `var_dump`. When I `echo` them, they are exactly the same. Same thing for `var_dump`. Except the character count. Where are these extra 4 (invisible) characters coming from?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try

```
var_dump(bin2hex($str1));
var_dump(bin2hex($str2));
```

or with

```
var_dump(htmlspecialchars($str1));
var_dump(htmlspecialchars($str2));
```

to inspect what's different, once found, paste here the different bits so we can figure out where the difference is from.

**EDIT:**

It's a `&` encoded as `&amp;` notice that `&` <-> `&amp;` are 4 chars different. what I think is going on is that you are sending a plain text emails, but entitizing the string, thus all `&` are becoming `&amp;`.

Comment: I edited the question above, `htmlspecialchars` will help spot html-entities related differences. check and paste the differences here.

Comment: From bin2hex: the POST string:  "715e25476c4f54434c3b3063476226616d703b49456e6768384d386376373a6e644 6614a7366214c564645777642583368456121774a435355346e344c55374b745e3a6 5715a5a36336b755431717240647623236153376968563023237955553844366c6a7 9507a36332139336a466e3850596c4947524b7935614f4e47686a43775423" ---the other one---: "715e25476c4f54434c3b306347622649456e6768384d386376373a6e6446614a736 6214c564645777642583368456121774a435355346e344c55374b745e3a65715a5a3 6336b755431717240647623236153376968563023237955553844366c6a79507a363 32139336a466e3850596c4947524b7935614f4e47686a43775423"

Comment: The spaces are only there for line break purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably one is UTF-8 and one is iso-8859-1 or some other different encoding.

Try utf_decode() on one of them and see if it matches.

Comment: I thought it might be this, but nothing I do seems to work. I tried changing the encoding type in the PHP.ini to UTF-8, as it is on my site. Then I also tried to use the encode/decode with utf8 and it gave the same results. I might just have a poor understanding of the situation though.

Answer (score 0):

This *might* be a sneaky encoding issue, where one string has a combining char like `å` stored as one unicode character, and the other string has it stored as two separate characters.

Comment: The only weird characters in it are: '!', '@', '#', '%', '^', '&', ':', ';'.

Comment: Its the "^" sign :)

Comment: Nevermind - in my case it was line-endings. \r\n vs \n. Looks the same, is not the same.

Comment: If you have that `\r\n` issue, like @RobQuist, you can use `json_encode` to detect it, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10209477/1809762

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto @aularon answer, using:

var_dump(htmlspecialchars($str1));

var_dump(htmlspecialchars($str2));

exposed that it was indeed `&amp;` in one and not the other string.

To solve, I used `htmlspecialchars_decode($str)` and that did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

In my case it happened due to html characters. i fixed like below,

try below code

```
var_dump(htmlspecialchars($str1));
var_dump(htmlspecialchars($str2));
```

if there is any html characters found then remove using strip_tags

```
strip_tags($str2)
```

Comment: Please do not copy-paste the accepted answer.