# How do I convert line breaks to \n 

Tags: php, javascript

I have a return string from a db.

The return string must be formatted in javascript.

```
<?php
    $db = "this is a line
           this is a new line";
?>
```

How would I convert the above to:

```
<?php $db = "this is a line \n this is a new line"; ?>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    var jdb = <?php echo $db; ?>
</script>
```

Comment: Another problem is that you are not inserting the string into JavaScript properly. It should be `var jdb = "<?php echo $db; ?>"`;

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this (updated 2014-11-08):

```
<?php

   $db = "this is a line
          this is a new line
          ";

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jdb = <?php echo json_encode($db) ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: i don't have  "\r\n" in my var $db
it's just textarea lines

Comment: If they are from a `<textarea>` they should *all* be `\r\n`. In any case, the above simply adjusts for the various line ending styles so that it should produce the same result for any.

Comment: you make my life looks easier :)

Comment: Can anyone explain how json_encode() does this?
@DaveRandom

Comment: This is how I managed to see value of PHP_EOL. Thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

```
$db = preg_replace("/\n/m", '\n', $db);
```

should do the trick

Comment: No need for `/m` when you don't use `^` or `$`, and your expression should be single-quoted ;-)

Comment: thanks, I didn't know this on using `m` modifier :)  _If there are no "\n" characters in a subject string, or no occurrences of ^ or $ in a pattern, setting this modifier has no effect._

Answer (score 5):

To properly preserve the `\r` and `\n` line breaks, you can easily use [strtr](https://www.php.net/strtr).

```
$db = strtr( $db, array(  "\n" => "\\n",  "\r" => "\\r"  ));
```

Comment: Contrary to using preg_replace with \n this does not display a warning. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

i don't get the point, but you can (escape the line break by adding a backslash)

```
$db = str_replace("\n","\\n",$db);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$db = str_replace("\r\n", "\\n", $db);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand correctly because \n is a line break!?

But you may be need:

```
$db = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $db);
```

Comment: i don't have  "\r\n" in my var $db
it's just textarea lines

Answer (score 0):

You want to output that to javascript... hmm, so if you want to insert it into html you probably want something like this (the test ran):

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
  $string = "123
  456"; // or $string = "123\n456";
  $string = str_replace(array("\r\n","\n"),"\\\\n",$string);
  echo "document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '".htmlentities($string)."';";
?>
</script>
```

with output `123\n 456` to the div through the js

If you simply want it as that in js, just remove two of the slashes so it's "\n" in php and "\n" in js.

Answer (score -3):

You should look at nl2br(), which converts all new lines to HTML <br />.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php