# Passing unescaped line break string from laravel to javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am fetching a string from Laravel that has line breaks. I want to pass it as a parameter to a JavaScript function, but I get unescaped line break error. how to escape these line breaks while I am passing it as a function parameter?

```
<p onclick="show('{{$user->detail}}')" > {{$user->name}} </p>

<script>
function show(detail){
var x = document.querySelector('.panel');
x.innerHTML= detail;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is your javascript on blade or its own file?

Comment: Try to include the details in a `div` and on click include that `div` inside the `.panel`

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message you are facing and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` will encode line breaks so that you can pass the multiline string to javascript. Using this method be sure to remove the inner `'`

```php
<p onclick="show({{ json_encode($user->detail) }})" > 
    {{$user->name}}
</p>
```

[How do I convert line breaks to \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209413/how-do-i-convert-line-breaks-to-n)